Async inside thread, bad idea?
Is async inside a dedicated thread a bad idea?
I've got a C# web app (REST) using System.Net.Http.HttpClient that streams video to a GUI via a multipart/x-mixed-replace REST endpoint, while simultaneously and continuously hitting a handful of other REST endpoints to obtain pseudo-realtime data to display over top of the video.  Everything is async.  When I allow the streaming video part to run on the UI thread, even though it's async it grinds everything else to a halt, the UI is entirely unresponsive.  To solve that I moved all of the video streaming part into its own thread and presto problem solved, the UI works nicely. But all of that code inside its own thread is async with awaits on the parts that call to the web server.  Since it's in a dedicated thread, is there any downside to either leaving it async, or changing it to all synchronous calls?  i.e. changing await Stream.ReadAsync() to Stream.Read()?  I tried it briefly but did not notice any obvious difference in performance, so I'm curious if there are any not-obvious pros or cons to using async in the worker thread?
Edit --> To clarify, I'm starting the thread this way:
new Thread(async () =>
{
    await neverEndingGetVideoFrames( async videoFrame =>
    {
        await displayVideoFrameAsync(videoFrame)
    });
}).Start();


If you can use threadpool thread you can take advantage of async await.
The advantage is that that dedicated thread can be freed to pool so maybe it can be used for other tasks. If thread doing io bound work, which in your case it seems to be, then it may be good idea.

A dedicated thread can't be freed to the ThreadPool.

@TheodorZoulias Cant the thread be freed if its from threadpool? I mean a pool thread can be used as a dedicated thread and it can be freed, no? For instance you can spawn a thread with task.run with a method which wont end by keep looping, do the work async and if it hits await it will be freed to pool. I think i ve tested this before.

Dedicated is a thread that has been created with the Thread constructor. This thread will do its assigned work and then it'll die. The ThreadPool will not claim it. The Task.Run uses ThreadPool threads, who by definition are not dedicated. Let's not create confusion about what "dedicated" means.

Dedicated thread sounds abstract to me it can be a thread from pool as well, if its not explicitly specified. I believe op didnt specifically mention type of thread so one can assume its a pool thread. And my idea was for a pool thread obviously.

Thanks for all the replies.  I updated the original question to show how I'm starting the thread.
